# How two Django applications use same database for authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication

previously we implemented one django application call it as "x" and it have own database and it have django default authentication system, now we need to create another related django application call it as "y", but y application did n't have database settings for y application authentication we should use x applications database and existing users in x application, so is it possible to implement like this?, if possible give the way how can we use same database for two separated django applications for authentication system.

Sorry for my english

Thanks for spending time for my query

Comment: You can set up two different database connections and use one for the `User` model and the other for the rest. However, you won't be able to use foreign keys to the user table, as they're not in the same database, so it's questionable how useful this is in practice. Enabling an API on the first app and using that for logins on the second might be more useful?

Comment: i have limition from my team we shouldn't use any data base configurations also

Comment: Wat? You’re supposed not to use the tool that Django gives you to do what you want to do‽

Answer (score 0):

So, to achieve this. In your second application, add `User` model in the `models.py` and remember to keep `managed=False` in the User model's Meta class.
Inside your `settings.py` have the same `DATABASES` configuration as of your first application.

By doing this, you can achieve the User model related functionality with ease in your new application.

Comment: i have limition from my team i should n't configure any database settings also in second app